# Saving and updating a child association object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a model like:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :revisions
end

class Revision < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Content
end
```

In my controller I am doing:

```
def create
  @content = Content.new(content_params)

  if @content.save
     # ...
  end
end
```

Content has:

```
- id
- category_id
- title
- body
- ..
```

Revision has:

```
- id
- category_id
- content_id
- body
```

So whenever I save/update/delete a Content the same thing should happened with the Revision.

Should I create a before_save to handle both situations using the same method?
How can I easily pass the category_id, content_id and body to the Revision?

**Update**

During an update, if I am updating a particular revision_id, I have to have that revision_id but not sure how to pass that when I am updating a Content instance.  Does that make sense?

Comment: **Never** name associations with `CamelCase`, they're `snake_case`: `belongs_to :content`

Comment: Rather than relying on application code to create revisions it may be better to use database triggers. In my experience triggers are much more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

I might take a look a [ActiveRecord::Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). Here is an example for how to use them:

```
 class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :revisions, dependent: :destroy

   after_commit :update_revision

   private

   def update_revision
     # Create or update a revision object
   end
 end
```

In general, I don't like the idea of creating another model using callbacks. It feels like a violation of the single responsibility principle. You might use a service object to handle the create and update operations you mentioned.

Note the `dependent: destroy` syntax on the `has_many` relationship as in the code block above. This will cascade deletes of a `Content` record to its related `Revision`s.

**Update**

If you just want to update a specific revision inside your controller, you could write:

```
 def create
   @content = Content.new(content_params)

   if @content.save
     Revision.find(revision_id).update_attributes!(...)
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question is to use a [`before_update`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback, *perhaps* with [`inverse_of`](https://viget.com/extend/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations) (so the associated objects are available in memory):

```
#app/models/content.rb
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :revisions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :revisions

  before_update :set_revision
  before_create :set_revision

  private

  def set_revision
     self.revisions.build body: self.body
  end
end

#app/models/revision.rb
class Revision < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :content
end
```

The above will create a new `revision` each time you `update` your `content` model. Both will save as you're using [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

---

As a recommendation, you *may* wish to look at the [`Paper Trail`](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem.

This does *exactly* what you're looking for (in terms of revisions) -- it saves any updates / edits you perform on a model.

```
#Gemfile
gem 'paper_trail'

$ rails generate paper_trail:install
$ rake db:migrate

#app/models/content.rb
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
end
```

This will automatically record the changes to the model *and* who performed it.

There is a [good RailsCast about it here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5L8fdZMRWLQ).